# FastAPI how to access bearer token

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm using FastAPI to create a simple api for automating my emails. I want to protect certain routes and I'm using this class:

```
import time

import jwt
from fastapi import HTTPException, Request
from fastapi.security import HTTPAuthorizationCredentials, HTTPBearer

#if you need to try it out just swap the following
from exchange_api.auth.jwt_handler import JWT_ALGORITHM, JWT_SECRET  

class JWTBearer(HTTPBearer):
    def __init__(self, auto_error: bool = True):
        super(JWTBearer, self).__init__(auto_error=auto_error)

    async def __call__(self, request: Request):
        credentials: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = await super(JWTBearer, self).__call__(request)
        if credentials:
            if not credentials.scheme == "Bearer":
                raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Invalid authentication scheme.")
            if not self.verify_jwt(credentials.credentials):
                raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Invalid token or expired token.")
            return credentials.credentials
        else:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=403, detail="Invalid authorization code.")


    def verify_jwt(self, jwtoken: str) -> bool:
        isTokenValid: bool = False

        try:
            payload = decodeJWT(jwtoken)
        except:
            payload = None
        if payload:
            isTokenValid = True
        return isTokenValid

def decodeJWT(token: str) -> dict:
        try:
            decoded_token = jwt.decode(token, JWT_SECRET, algorithms=[JWT_ALGORITHM])
            return decoded_token if decoded_token["expiration"] >= time.time() else None
        except:
            return {}
```

Then I wanted to protect certain routes:

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException, Request, Header

from exchange_api.auth.jwt_bearer import JWTBearer

@auth_router.get("/protected", dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearer())], tags=["auth test"])
def get_user_data():
    #my issue: I'd like to access the token and its payload
    return {}
```

I have no issues with my code so far. But I'd like to periodically refresh the token and I need its payload anyway to do things inside my functions. How can I do that? I don't want my users to get kicked out in the middle of their session because their token expired.

It works fine without depends and using the token as the body of the various routes but I don't think that's the right way to do this. fastapi-jwt-auth is too old and it generates dependencies conflicts with my already installed libraries.

EDIT: What I mean is that I want to access the bearer token that my users submitted to authenticate to do various things and also because I plan to substitute it with a new one every time the users call a protected route but WITHOUT the need to authenticate again.

EDIT: I managed to get the token:

```
@auth_router.get("/protected", dependencies=[Depends(JWTBearer())], tags=["auth test"])
def get_user_data(request: Request):
    token = request.headers["authorization"]
    return {token}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to suggest returning the token within your auth function, but then I saw you figured it out.

I'd also recommend using [FastAPI-Another-JWT-Auth](https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-another-jwt-auth/). It speeds things up, declutters everything, and has most of the functions you might need built in. It's a fork of the old main one which is deprecated and no longer maintained.

```
async def some_function(auth: AuthJWT = Depends()):
    auth.access_token_required()
```

If you need the token subject, you just do:

```
user_id = auth.get_jwt_subject()
```

If you want to set a new jwt each time, you just do:

```
new_access_token = auth.create_access_token()
auth.set_access_token(new_access_token)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will show you how I approach JWT tokens in my FastAPI apps. I use library [python-jose](https://pypi.org/project/python-jose/).

In my `auth.py` file I have the following code:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from typing import Literal

from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer
from jose import JWTError, jwt

from app.models import User
from app.settings import access_token_jwk, refresh_token_jwk

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="auth/token")


def authenticate_user(email: str, password: str) -> User:
    # Here you would verify password against hash from database
    # or authenticate any other way you want. This function
    # will be used in endpoint /token.
    ...

def create_token(
    user: User,
    token_type: Literal["refresh", "access"],
    ttl: int
) -> str:
    # This function generates token with any claims you want

    payload = {
        "sub": user.email,
        "iat": datetime.utcnow(),
        "exp": datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=ttl),
        "user_role": user.role,
    }

    if token_type == "access":
        key = access_token_jwk
    elif token_type == "refresh":
        key = refresh_token_jwk

    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(
        payload,
        key,
        "HS256"
    )

    return encoded_jwt

async def decode_access_token(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme) -> dict:
    # This function will be used as dependency in endpoints
    # we want secured. Basically it verifies the JWT and
    # returns its contents as dictionary.

    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(
            token,
            access_token_jwk,
            algorithms="HS256",
        )
    except JWTError as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail=f"Invalid token: {e}"
        )

    return payload

async def decode_refresh_token(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme) -> dict:
    # This function will be used as dependency only
    # when you want to refresh your access token.
    # Since access and refresh tokens have different signing keys,
    # user won't be able to use refresh token to access endpoints
    # protected by access token.

    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(
            token,
            refresh_token_jwk,
            algorithms="HS256",
        )
    except JWTError as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail=f"Invalid token: {e}"
        )

    return payload
```

Then my endpoint for getting token looks like this:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordRequestForm

from app.auth import authenticate_user, create_token, decode_refresh_token
from app.users import get_user

router = APIRouter()


@router.post("/token")
async def login_for_access_token(
    form_data: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends()
):
    # If authenticate_user() fails, exception from within the function
    # will be raised.
    user = authenticate_user(form_data.username, form_data.password)

    access_token = create_token(user, "access", 60)
    refresh_token = create_token(user, "refresh", 60*24*3)
    return {
        "access_token": access_token,
        "refresh_token": refresh_token,
        "token_type": "bearer"
    }

@router.post("/token/refresh")
async def refresh_access_token(
    token: dict = Depends(decode_refresh_token)
):
    user = get_user(token.get["sub"]) # arbitrary function to get user by email
    access_token = create_token(user, "access", 60)
    refresh_token = create_token(user, "refresh", 60*24*3)
    return {
        "access_token": access_token,
        "refresh_token": refresh_token,
        "token_type": "bearer"
    }
```

That's it, use `decode_access_token()` as dependency in any endpoint you want to secure and it will automatically read token from header and verify it:

```py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from app.auth import decode_access_token

router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/secure/route")
def get_secured_data(token: dict = Depends(decode_access_token)):
    # under token variable you can access token data and claims
    ...
```